# Transfer Crypto Currency between exchanges

Tags: exchanges

How do I transfer BTC from one exchange to the other?

Comment: the question seems to be a bit too broad, the whole idea of bitcoin is to transfer coins. Also exchanges do allow this, e.g. when I transfer from HitBTC to BitTRex. I assume you want to ask for a specific use case, maybe need to be a bit more clear in your description...

Answer (score 1):

I would downvote this but I can’t so I’ll just answer it :(  Of course, easy and direct transferrence is the primary function of Bitcoin. Exchanges have a “deposit funds” function/button that provides the address for you to send the BTC from your current exchange or wallet. Just go to “send” or “withdraw” on your current exchange and plug in the new exchange’s (or another person’s) address and send it to the network. That’s it.